# QtCreator returns error "Cannot change to working directory"

Tags: c++, linux, qt, qt-creator

I'm trying to running a simple HelloWorld program with Qt Creator
Code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  cout << "Hello World!" << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

When running occurs the error

```
Cannot change to working directory '/home/myusername/build-myproject-Desktop-Debug': file or directory not found
```

Many tutorials in the internet tell me to disable "Run in terminal", but I need this for my project.
My working directory is /home/myusername/build-myproject-Desktop-Debug

Any help?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Which OS are you running?

I'm on Linux and had the same problem. My solution was to use xterm and set the default Terminal in Qtcreator to xterm (In the menu: Tools, then Options, then Environment, then Terminal, there "/usr/bin/xterm -e")

Comment: Lubuntu (Linux/Debian/Ubuntu), but why it doesn't work with LXTerminal?

Comment: @PEAR: Did the Qt settings include the "-e" too, when it was set to lxterminal?

Comment: @jewirth: Yes, when it is set to LXTerminal the command is: x-terminal-emulator -e

Answer (score 3):

You can install Terminator terminal (sudo apt-get install terminator) and use it as Qt Creator terminal:

Tools->Options->Enviroment->System->Terminal->"/usr/bin/terminator -x"